# Drupal Drush: Drush command terminated abnormally due to an unrecoverable error

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, drush

When I try to run Drush from the command line, I get the following error:

`Drush command terminated abnormally due to an unrecoverable error`

I am not sure why this is happening and I can't figure out what is wrong with it. When I run `drush -d -v status` I get the following output:

```
$ drush -d -v status

Bootstrap to phase 0. [0.04 sec, 1.87 MB][bootstrap]
Drush bootstrap phase : _drush_bootstrap_drush() [0.04 sec, 1.98 MB] [bootstrap]

Cache HIT cid: 6.2.0-commandfiles-0-db3247e83fac7ae8173ddf4f9e97733a [0.05 sec, 2[MB][debug]

Bootstrap to phase 0. [0.15 sec, 5.25 MB][bootstrap]
Drush bootstrap phase : _drush_bootstrap_drupal_root() [0.19 sec, 5.25 MB] [bootstrap]

Initialized Drupal 7.35 root directory at /home/cms/production/website [0.21 sec, 6.14 MB][notice]

Drush bootstrap phase : _drush_bootstrap_drupal_site() [0.21 sec, 6.15 MB][bootstrap]

Initialized Drupal site default at sites/default [0.21 sec, 6.15 MB][notice]

Cache MISS cid: 6.2.0-install_profile-66ecfeb9791a023150773849f1550c5d [0.22 sec, 6.15 MB][debug]

Cache HIT cid: 6.2.0-commandfiles-2-90b5571ff64221f80c3320ec33b2ed28 [0.22 sec, 6.15 MB][debug]

Drush bootstrap phase : _drush_bootstrap_drupal_configuration() [0.22 sec, 6.44 MB][bootstrap]

Drush command terminated abnormally due to an unrecoverable error. [0.25 sec, 7.61 MB][error]
```

Wondering if anyone has run into this issue and found a solution.

Answer (score 2):

1. Check errors at watchdog page inside Drupal. If site produces errors drush commands will fail.
2. If your site uses special configuration (not under sites/default) you should add '-l domain.name' to each your drush command.

Comment: This is an interesting analogy. I did not think it matter, but that could be an issue. We are running a few sites within a multi-site system sharing the same drupal core, using Domain Access. I will give this a try and post back...

Comment: I am facing the same problem, could post your solution back please. thanks

Answer (score 2):

maybe it is to old this message, but I found this article very usefull, and also It worked for me.

First check if your site has drupal_goto out of custom modules, theses calls should check if drupal is on cli mode, if not, then you can make an "drupal_goto" instrucción.

Full list:

- Look for calls to drupal_goto. These calls should be wrapped in a call to drupal_is_cli before doing a drupal_goto.
- Look for calls to 'exit;' in the code path
- Make sure the uri in the drush alias is exactly as it is accessed in browser.
- Make a brand new install of Drupal and see if the problem happens again. If not , what is different between the sites?
- Some modules that can cause this problem include require_login, secure_site, mobile_tools, restrict_ip

The original post here: https://www.drupal.org/node/1140842

Answer (score 0):

It's very likely that this is occurring do to one of the modules that are enabled. Unfortunately the debugging output doesn't give any further information as to which module it is.

If this is in a development environment, I would suggest that you start disabling contributed modules one-by-one until this error goes away. I would start with any modules that are specifically expecting browser use, perhaps a module like 'mobile tools' or a contributed module that possibly redirects the user.